# How to get all unique words on a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, nlp

I'm loading a dataset of reviews into pandas, as part of the processing I want to get all the unique words to create a **Bag of Words**.

[image]

Since the text is contained in several rows I first have to merge them.

I tried this:

```
all_text = df['review_body'].to_string()
words = set(a.split(' '))
words = list(words)
```

But I'm getting incorrect words from there like:

```
u'fel...\n1093'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
words = " ".join(df.review_body).split()
```

---

If you want to retain only unique non-numeric strings, I'd suggest a set comprehension:

```
words = {
    x for x in ' '.join(
        df.review_body.str.lower().tolist()
    ).split() if x.isalpha()
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Suppose the dataframe is as below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'review_body': ['This is review 1', 'This is other review 2', 'this is third review 3']})
print(df)
```

Result:

```
              review_body
0        This is review 1
1  This is other review 2
2  this is third review 3
```

Then, you can try following, using `cat`, followed by `lower` and `split`:

```
result = set(df['review_body'].str.cat(sep=' ').lower().split())
print(result)
```

Result:

```
{'this', 'is', 'third', 'other', '3', 'review', '2', '1'}
```

Comment: I like your cat solution for succinctness. ;) However, from my experience, join is a few ticks faster.

Answer (score 2):

Just for the sake of playing around and giving more options :)

```
df["review_body"].str.lower().str.split(" ").apply(pd.Series).stack().unique()
```

i.e. lower and split, then stack all words and use `unique()`

Answer (score -1):

Not enough rep to comment, but in addition to the answers provided above, you can use regex to remove characters you don't want in your strings.

```
import re
string = 'this is a \nstring'
cleanstring = re.sub('[\n]', '', string)
```

Output:

```
'this is a string'
```

This will help you clean the data to identify true unique words, and not consider \nstring and string as two different words.

Comment: This has nothing to do with pandas.